# Performance of evaluating a mathematical expression over large data

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Given 100,000 sequences of length 1000,
I am trying to calculate, for each m~[1, 1000], the percentage of sequences for which to following expression holds -

```
|(Mean of first m numbers in the sequens) - 0.25 | >= 0.1
```

The way the data was created:

```
data = np.random.binomial(1, 0.25, (100000, 1000))
```

What i have tried:

```
In Main Function:
    bad_sequence_percentage = []
    for l in range(0, sequence_length):
        bad_sequence_percentage.append(c(l+1, 0.1))  # (number of examples, epsilon)




The helping function:
def c(number_of_examples, curr_epsilon):
    print("number of examples: " + str(number_of_examples))
    num_of_bad_sequences = 0

    for i in range(0, num_of_sequences):
        if abs(np.mean(data[i][0:number_of_examples]) - 0.25) >= curr_epsilon:
            num_of_bad_sequences += 1

    print(str(number_of_examples) + " : " + str(num_of_bad_sequences))

    return num_of_bad_sequences / 100000
```

The problem is that it takes ages - about 1 m/sec.

Is there a way to change the implementation such that it'll take much less time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
avg = data.cumsum(1)/np.arange(1,data.shape[1]+1).astype(float)
curr_epsilon = 0.1
out = np.count_nonzero(np.abs(avg - 0.25) >= curr_epsilon,axis=0)/100000.0
```

Steps involved :

- Make use of `cumsum` to simulate the constantly incrementing windowed-averaging computation. For the average part, we just need to divide the cumulative summations by the range(length_of_array). This forms the basis of vectorization here.
- Rest of the part is a simple port with `np.abs` replacing `abs` for NumPy supported vectorization. Then, we compare and get the counts with `np.count_nonzero`.

**Runtime test and verification**

Approaches -

```
def c(number_of_examples, curr_epsilon):
    num_of_sequences = data.shape[0]
    num_of_bad_sequences = 0
    for i in range(0, num_of_sequences):
        if abs(np.mean(data[i][0:number_of_examples]) - 0.25) >= curr_epsilon:
            num_of_bad_sequences += 1
    return num_of_bad_sequences / 100000.0

def original_approach(data):
    sequence_length = data.shape[1]
    bad_sequence_percentage = []
    for l in range(0, sequence_length):
        bad_sequence_percentage.append(c(l+1, 0.1))
    return bad_sequence_percentage

def vectorized_approach(data):
    avg = data.cumsum(1)/np.arange(1,data.shape[1]+1).astype(float)
    curr_epsilon = 0.1
    out = np.count_nonzero(np.abs(avg - 0.25) >= curr_epsilon,axis=0)/100000.0
    return out
```

Timings

```
In [5]: data = np.random.binomial(1, 0.25, (1000, 1000))

In [6]: np.allclose(original_approach(data), vectorized_approach(data))
Out[6]: True

In [7]: %timeit original_approach(data)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.35 s per loop

In [8]: %timeit vectorized_approach(data)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop

In [9]: 7350.0/10.9
Out[9]: 674.3119266055046
```

**`670x+`** speedup there!

With bigger dataset :

```
In [4]: data = np.random.binomial(1, 0.25, (10000, 1000))

In [5]: %timeit original_approach(data)
1 loops, best of 3: 1min 15s per loop

In [6]: %timeit vectorized_approach(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 98.7 ms per loop

In [7]: 75000.0/98.7
Out[7]: 759.8784194528876
```

The speedup jumped to **`750x+`**!

I am hoping with the originally asked dataset `np.random.binomial(1, 0.25, (100000, 1000))`, the speedups would be even better.

Comment: Thank you. But for `np.random.binomial(1, 0.25, (100000, 1000))`, i am getting "out of memory" error.

Comment: @AlexGoft To save on memory, if you don't mind changing the input array, use cumsum to change the input array with its `out` param to write back results into input. Refer to docs on more info - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html

Answer (score 1):

alternatively one could replace the following for loop

```
num_of_bad_sequences = 0
for i in range(0, num_of_sequences):
        if abs(np.mean(data[i][0:number_of_examples]) - 0.25) >= curr_epsilon:
            num_of_bad_sequences += 1
```

with

```
num_of_bad_sequences = np.sum(
    np.abs(np.mean(data[:,0:number_of_examples], axis = 1) - 0.25) >= curr_epsilon
)
```